# How to download xlsx file using JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I am developing a JMeter script for testing download feature. This will download an xlsx file. This is how the script is set up:

```
Transaction Controller

   Download 1 - HTTP request
   Download 2 - HTTP request
   Download 3 - HTTP request
```

Download 1 is a POST call whereas Download 2 and Download 3 are GET calls. Download 1 has the download link in the response. I am extracting that and passing to Download 2 and Download 3. I have added Save Data to File listener to Download 3. I have entered the download location to Filename prefix field in the above listener. After the test is executed I observed that the file is downloaded but the extension of the file is .sheet. It is s SHEET type file. I observed that the size of this file (downloaded through JMeter) matches with the file size when manually downloaded but when I try to open the file it asks me to select an app to open. Now as this is a .sheet file so I believe I cannot open using MS Excel. So I wanted to understand what changes should I make so that the file is downloaded with a .xlsx extension. I believe that I am downloading the correct file but the format seems incorrect. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to save the file with the name completely defined by you you need to tick the following boxes:

- `Don't add number to prefix`
- `Don't add content type suffix`

and provide the "Filename prefix" as the desired location and name of the destination file.

If you plan to run the test with multiple threads and loops you can consider generating different result files for that using relevant [JMeter Functions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) and/or variables like [__threadNum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) or [__groovy()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy)

[image]

More information: [JMeter Performance Testing: Upload & Download Scenarios](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-testing)